# Values are not showing using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to display data inside text field and those values will be fetched dynamically.But i am not getting any value(only blank filed is coming) when show action is executing.

Please check mu code given below.

## Views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <input type="text",value="<%= @post.name %>">
</p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <input type="text",value="<%= @post.title %>">
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <input type="text",value="<%= @post.content %>">
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Remove the comma between the input="text" and value=.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the value Property by removing quotes as:
`<input type="text",value=<%= @post.content %>>`

Comment: you can also use it as : <input type = "text", value = "#{@post.content}" >